# Map repeated values in presto

Tags: presto, trino

I'm extracting data from JSON and mapping two arrays in presto.It works fine when there are no repeated values in the array but fails with error - **Duplicate map keys are not allowed** if any of the values are repeated.I need those values and cannot remove any of the values from the array.Is there a work around for this scenario?
Sample values:

```
 array1 -- [Rewards,NEW,Rewards,NEW]
 array2 -- [losg1,losg2,losg3,losg4]
```

Map key/value has to be generated like this [Rewards=>losg1,NEW=>losg2,Rewards=>losg3,NEW=>losg4]

Comment: Since you want to keep duplicate mappings, you cannot represent this as a `map`. Consider representing as an `ARRAY(ROW(k, v))` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the response but i'm not able to  fix the issue. Can you please explain with this example?What needs to be done differently so the mapping can be done like this? 1-> 2,2->3,1->4                                                                                                        
                                    select MAP(ARRAY[1,2,1],array[2,3,4]);

Comment: Pairs of associations can be returned like this `SELECT ARRAY[ROW('Rewards', 'losg1'), ROW('NEW', 'losg2'), ROW('Rewards', 'losg3')]`.

Comment: You're welcome. Converted into an answer, so the question can be marked as answered/accepted. I invite you to join [Trino (formerly Presto SQL) community slack](https://trino.io/slack.html) where you can get help in cases that do not fit SO scope.

Answer (score 0):

Pairs of associations can be returned like this:

```
SELECT ARRAY[ROW('Rewards', 'losg1'), ROW('NEW', 'losg2'), ROW('Rewards', 'losg3')]
```